# Open Chat Widget in new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zendesk

I am using the Zendesk Chat API and rendering the component with React, which is then rendered on to the Zendesk templates via JavaScript.

Currently I am trying to move the chat widget into a separate window when they click on the Chat Box.

The problem is, since the whole chat Box is just a React component, I can''t just open a new window since there is no url that just servers the Chat Box, including all the state and data that is already going on inside the chat widget. My plan was, whenever the user clicks on the Chat Widget, it would open the Chat Widget up in a new window with window.open(), but would I have to wrap the whole React Component (the Chat Widget) inside an iFrame so the State and everything else carries over to the new window.

I am unsure how I can do this.

Comment: Can you change the route?

Comment: Route? There is not react router set up. It is just being rendered via Vanilla JS. The Zendesk template loads the js for the React, the react component itself has no routes.

Comment: The code needs to exist in its own HTML page. If you try to do more manipulation via javascript other then opening the window on button click, the browser will block it as a popup. It is better to have the link open without async calls.

Comment: Store state of ChatBox in localStorage and recreate it bigger in new window (by route)? chat probably also saves data to restore `session` on refresh - should e restore/recreate his own state itself?

Comment: @mattdevio 
I am aware I have to serve it through some sort of HTML page, but the problem with that is the I do not have a server for this HTML page. That is why I wanted to create the html inside the iframe and reference the JS for React again, but how can I open up this iframe in a new window with all the state, etc